# Journey Builder - Salesforce Data Event - have multiple fields in entry criteria but only fire on change of one field

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, entry-criteria

I am building a Subscriber Welcome journey. The entry event is a Salesforce Data Event that looks at Contact in SF.

When the Subscription Status picklist is set to Subscribed, it should fire the event. This should happen the first time and all subsequent times that that field is changed and the new value is subscribed. I have this working.

Then, if the above happens, the contact should only enter the journey if Contact Type = Consumer

So some scenarios:

Contact Type = Consumer, Subscriptions Status ISCHANGED to Subscribed > Enter Journey

Contact Type ISCHANGED to Consumer, Subscriptions Status = Subscribed > Do Not Enter Journey

In other words, Subscription Status is the trigger, while Contact Type is more of a filter.

The Salesforce Data Event has the Entry Criteria page and then the Entry Filter page. Entry Filter is where I thought to set this but it only allows related object fields to be selected. I have tried some different combinations of Entry Criteria but I can't seem to achieve scenario two from above.

I know that I can control this on the Salesforce side by, say, creating a new checkbox field and using workflow rules to update this checkbox, then use this checkbox in the entry criteria. However, I want to avoid this if possible.

Is there a way to achieve this on the Entry Criteria alone?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's impossible to do with Entry Criteria based on record update. If you want to keep it on SFMC side, you can however pass Contact Type as Entry Data and make a decision split as first step in your journey. In that decision split check for Contact Type value, and for all undesirables exit person from a journey.